# Twitter API Error for Users/Lookup Method

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using the [EpiTwitter API](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/twitter-php-oauth.html) library for PHP. It seems to work fine to get data and even post data to Twitter. But I get a **"Incorrect signature"** error from Twitter when trying to use the [Users/Lookup](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/24142947/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3a-users-lookup) method.

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
$twtObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauthToken, $oauthSecret);
$creds = $twtObj->get('/users/lookup.json?screen_name=dougw,raffi');
echo $creds->responseText;
```

Other methods works fine, example:

```
$creds = $twtObj->get('/users/show.json?screen_name=dougw');
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on the [twitter Async Github](https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async/issuesearch?state=closed&q=lookup#issue/79) thanks to jmathai

Need to use:

```
$creds = $twtObj->get('/users/lookup.json', array('screen_name' => 'dougw,raffi'));
```

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it